# Can you use the isolation forest algorithm on large sample sizes?

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, anomaly-detection, subsampling, isolation-forest

The original isolation forest paper states that the algorithm works best on small subsamples, but is it okay to use it on large sample sizes or are other anomaly detection algorithms better?

Comment: Could you include resources like the link to the paper you specified?

Comment: Depends. What bad thing are you worried might happen if you use isolation forest on a large data set? Does the article you mention have anything that might answer that question?

Comment: @Pluviophile https://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/icdm08b.pdf?q=isolation-forest

Comment: @Sycorax says Reinstate Monica,
I am just curious if this is bad practice since the original paper mentions that the algorithm works best on small sample sizes. It seems to be working great for me, I am just curious if anyone has found that another algorithm works better.

Comment: What I mean is "works best" could mean different things. It could mean "this algorithm doesn't scale well because it has a high computational cost that increases rapidly with data size, so it rapidly becomes infeasible" or it could mean "this algorithm produces bogus results on large data but not on small data." I'm trying to delineate in which sense you mean "best."

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica, I'm more concerned with the latter. The computational cost is a small concern though because I will be required to re-train the data periodically on a monthly basis. The bogus results are what really worry me because I don't want to risk false positives and false negatives from overriding ```max_samples``` where: "If max_samples is larger than the number of samples provided, all samples will be used for all trees (no sampling)."